# Using ARD to set SSID, but users get keychain login prompt

Tags: terminal

I am trying to "blast" out the credentials for our next enterprise wireless SSID to all of our users using unix commands via Apple Remote Desktop. I did this flawlessly several years ago when I created the current netork/SSID. When the process gets to this command"networksetup -addpreferredwirelessnetworkatindex en0 [SSID] 0 WPA2 [Passphrase]", a popup reading, "network setup wants to use the 'login' keychain. Please enter the keychain password."

I am running the command as root and the network is added no matter what, but how can I eliminate that popup from appearing so as to not get 200 support calls/tickets?

Clients are 11" Airs running 10.10, 10.11, 10.12.

Comment: Could you add all the commands you are currently using to your question?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to add a WiFi network with authentication to a number of Macs is to use a profile.

You can build the profile with `Apple Configurator 2`, copy it onto the Mac and then install it using the `profiles` command. So long as you are not targeting macOS 10.13 it is quite easy. For 10.13 it gets harder.